# How to use react-native-screens with react-navigation v4?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have read a title which `react-native-screens` package make faster the `react-native` navigation while using `react-navigation`.

And I dont find a good help of usage.

Now I want to know

1. Do I need to install this package separately?
2. Is it built into react-navigation in before?
3. If it is built in before, So Do I need to use it or it is used already?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `react-native-screens` and import the navigator from there: https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens#using-native-stack-navigator

Couple of things to note:

- You need to have `react-navigation-stack` installed as well
- The navigator from `react-native-screens` isn't as customizable, which might be okay depending on your case
- As far as I have tried, it's a bit buggy right now

React Navigation 5 (alpha) has an official integration for it: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/native-stack-navigator.html

But all the previous points apply.

Comment: What is difference between `createStackNavigator ` and `createNativeStackNavigator ` ?

Comment: What is difference between `createStackNavigator ` and `createNativeStackNavigator ` ?

Answer (score -1):

None of the package mentioned is built in. You have to install it as per their installation doc. If your project is large please use react-navigation, you'll get good support and large community using it.